# Windows service incorrect function

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am currently creating a Windows service.  I've got everything finished and can deploy it to me test server.  But when I try to start the service I get `Error 1: Incorrect function`.  The weird thing is that it's happening on a method call.  The relevant code sections look like this:

```
public CacheManager(Logger logger, QueueSettings settings)
{
    _logger = logger;

    _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.1");
    FillCache();
    _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.2");
}

    private void FillCache()
    {
        _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.1.1");
        Utils.RefreshSession(ref _session, _user, _password, _appServer);
        _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.1.2");
        Parts = new PartCache(ref _session);
        _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.1.3");
        Customers = new CustomerCache(ref _session);
        _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.1.4");

        lastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
        _logger.WriteLog("checkpoint #1.1.5");
    }
```

According to the logs, I am reaching checkpoint #1.1 but not checkpoint #1.1.1.  The error that is coming back is:

```
Could not start the JediProcessDocuments service on the local computer.

Error1: Incorrect function.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you inline the FillCache() code into the constructor? Does it execute correctly?

Comment: Do you have a call stack?  Is FillCache in the same assembly as CacheManager?

Comment: Could the problem be inside _logger.WriteLog(), maybe after it writes the output?  What does that function do?

Comment: @Philipp: the first thing that happens is that I smack myself for not thinking of something so obvious.  When I try it, I don't even get to checkpoint #1.1 (there is a checkpoint #1 in the class that creates CacheManager, so I know something is getting executed).

Comment: @JohnD: Sorry, I should have explained better: CacheManager is the constructor of a class called CacheManager.  FillCache is a private method of the class.

Comment: So the issue is happening outside the code you are showing above. Maybe it is time to expand the code sample.

Comment: Does your _logger have AutoFlush enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that the DLL containing the Session object (the variable _session in the code sample wasn't deployed).  I guess that windows services defer loading DLLs until the actual method that needs the DLL is called and doesn't detect the non-presence until then.

Comment: Can I ask you how did you solve this? I have read your answer but can't say I have understand it(still Junior) I get same error. The code is working on my windows 10 machine but once I install my application to windows server 2016 it's not working anymore. I use kernell32.dll and my application is 32 bit

Comment: @ShinoLex: IIRC there was a dll that was part of the project that wasn't being deployed to the server. It turns out that .NET first loads a .DLL only when a function that requires that DLL is needed. If you're seeing the same problem, check to make sure all of your DLLs are being deployed to your server

Comment: I have solved my problem. It was not related with missing DLL's instead of the function that I was using on my machine seems like not working on Linux file system. I was testing on my machine with NTFS file system and it was working nice and smoot now I have to find another way to get an unique identifier from folders on that linux storage